# Difference between by the time and when

Tags: time-reference

> By the time I left my apartment, my friend was still there, so he might have taken it.

> When I left the apartment, my friend was still there, so he might have taken it.

I know what 2nd expression means, but not so sure about the first expression. Does it convey the same meaning as the 2nd expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first expression does not quite work. You could say:

> At the time I left my apartment, my friend was still there, so he might have taken it.

this is because we are using our knowledge of the friend's location **at** a particular time, that at which we left the apartment.

We use the term

> By the time

to talk about events occurring in a period **up to** a certain time

> By the time I woke up my friend had already left

or in the famous song

> By the time I get to Phoenix she'll be rising ...